# created xlsx file using saveWorkbook() in R but can't open the file

Tags: xlsx

I've run the below code which creates the xlsx file in my directory. If i try opening the file in excel an error message appears asking to try one of the following:

1. Make sure you are permitted to access this file or drive.
2. Make sure there is enough memory and disk space.
3. Make sure this file is recognizable format.
   (D:\my_xlsx_file.xlsx)

I can access other files not created within R without a problem. Why would this file not be opening?

```
 saveWorkbook(wb, "my_xlsx_file.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried again the next day and this time i can open the file with no problem. Makes sense!